# Assigning to reference type parameter

Tags: c#

I'm implementing binary tree, and have encountered some problems with understanding of reference types.

This is not implementation itself, but piece of code that produces confusion in my head.

```
class SomeType { }
class BinaryTree
{
    public SomeType root = null;

    public void Add(SomeType something)
    {
        Insert(root, something);
    }

    private void Insert(SomeType current, SomeType newItem)
    {
        if(current == null)
            current = newItem;
    }

}
```

And the usage

```
void Main()
{
    DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
    ds.Add(new SomeType());
    Console.WriteLine(ds.root);
}
```

Which produces `null` to console.

The question is, when I'm calling `Insert` method, passing `root` as reference, and then assigning to `current` new object, I expect it to appear under `root` field, because I passed a reference, right? But instead i got `null` under `root`.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Reference types are still passed by value. They’re references to objects, not variables. When you assign `current = newItem`, you’re replacing the reference that `current` contains with a new one, not replacing the contents of the object that `current` references. (If you’re coming from another language, you might be more familiar with calling this type of thing a “pointer”.)

Comment: If you want to modify the variable that you're passing in, you'll have to add the `ref` modifier to that parameter.

Comment: @Ry- It makes sense for me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type parameter by value, it is possible to change the data belonging to the referenced object, such as the value of a class member. 
**However, you cannot change the value of the reference itself; for example, you cannot use the same reference to allocate memory for a new class and have it persist outside the method. To do that, pass the parameter using the `ref` or `out` keyword.**

Documentation: [Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

Basically the problem arises on this line:

```
current = newItem;
```

To make it work as you expected, and keep this code structure, then do this:

```
class SomeType { }
class BinaryTree
{
    public SomeType root = null;

    public void Add(SomeType something)
    {
        Insert(ref root, something);
    }

    private void Insert(ref SomeType current, SomeType newItem)
    {
        if (current == null)
            current = newItem;
    }
}
```

And the usage

```
void Main()
{
    DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
    ds.Add(new SomeType());
    Console.WriteLine(ds.root);
}
```

Comment: That opening paragraph is terribly confusing to me.

Comment: This paragraph explains that a reference type points to the data; Then following paragraph explains that we can not change that reference without using the ref or out.

Comment: Telling me what it explains doesn't make it explain it any better. It's not at all clear in my opinion.